# Error al momento de llamar una clase en python

Tags: python, poo

Tengo el siguiente código para mandar llamar una clase:

```
nn = NeuralNetwork([2,3,2],activation = "tanh")
```

La clase NeuralNetwork esta declarada correctamente sin embargo me marca lo siguiente:

```
  nn = NeuralNetwork([2,3,2],activation = "tanh")
```

> NameError: name 'NeuralNetwork' is not defined

Aun soy nuevo en python.

Comment: puedes mandar todo el codigo?, por lo menos los imports

Comment: El nombre de que usaste para declarar la clase y el nombre que usas para instanciarla no es el mismo. Creo que eso debe de ser

Comment: Hola Daniel, el error solo indica que el identificado `NeuralNetwork` no existe en el momento que intentas instanciar. Las causas pueden ser múltiples, incluido un typo, sin ver el código donde defines la clase y los imports si los hay (está definida en otro módulo) va a ser difícil saber dónde está el error. también es importante que no intentes instanciarla en el script antes de ser definida o importada. Intenta añadir más información usando el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/261660/edit) que hay debajo de la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: si pahi van los codigos de import en la clase NeuralNetwork  import numpy as np
Y el de la clase numpy no tiene ningun import pero se manda llamar la clase NeuralNetwork con nn = NeuralNetwork([2,3,2],activation = "tanh")

Comment: No me permite subir todo el codigo pero en el modulo ejecutable numpy solo referencio la clase del modulo NeuralNetwork. y en el modulo NeuralNetwork.py hago el import numpy as np. todo lo saque del siguiente sitio http://www.aprendemachinelearning.com/crear-una-red-neuronal-en-python-desde-cero/